# How to get insert time or last updated time as field in MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb

In a MongoDB table multiple records will be inserted at a time.

For example below records will the same timestamp

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("567a68517507b377a0a20902"), value: "bar", time: "2012" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("567a68517507b377a0a20903"), value: "baz", time: "2011" }
```

It's possible to get the timestamp of individual document.

```
ObjectId("567a68517507b377a0a20903").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2015-12-23T09:24:33Z")
```

Is it possible to have a field where it automatically generates the last updated or created timestamp to each and every document upon insert?

Similar to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in MYSQL

Note: Data will be inserted from Apache Spark Streaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your language, yes. In MongoShell, you can use `new ISODate()`

Comment: I insert the data from Apache Spark

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [$currentDate](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/currentDate/). But it works only in update query.